# Can't open PID file mysqld.pid (yet?) after start: Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb, centos7

```
[root@185-114-23-149 ~]# systemctl status mysqld -l
* mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Fri 2020-05-08 20:22:11 UTC; 3min 20s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 2377 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2360 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysqld.service
           `-2379 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

May 08 20:22:11 185-114-23-149 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
May 08 20:22:15 185-114-23-149 systemd[1]: Can't open PID file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (yet?) after start: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Can't open because mysql.pid file don't exist. I can't find any file like this. What should I do to fix this error? or is it error? because when I send command which is "systemctl start mysqld", console doesn't return, hangs!
**(I use it on Centos 7)**

Comment: See the cause and resolution sections at the bottom of [this page](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035549754-Systemctl-fails-to-start-service-Too-many-levels-of-symbolic-links-)

Comment: Sounds like a loop in `ln -s ...`

Comment: it's solved. I installed it and set up again. It would be caused by momentary error